# Can we set an Aspx var and use it in all other pages like Php Include

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net

In an Aspx site, I need to set some variable that never change and can be used in all other pages (in php site i use a include file) and i include that file in every other pages.

Trying that method in Aspx that don't run.

How i can solve the prob.

Tnx.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: No, i don't want other users write the code for me ...

Comment: No, i don't want other users write the code for me ... i've tried the  <!-- #Include virtual="/includes/file.aspx" -->  that work great and the file was included but the variable was just used and limited to that file. Now i've tried to put some String Var in another include file calling that var with a response.write(myVar) on the sub page but i got this error : "'zzz' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Comment: Declare it as `Friend Shared` in global.asax

Answer (score 0):

You can use public readonly property
public readonly int MyVal = 5;

Then you can access creating object of that class
or make property as Static

Comment: Thank you, i've solved that prob adding  Application("MyVar") = "VarValue" in the Global.asa calling that var with <% MyVar %> on all the others pages.